# IIS 7 re-write - can I get rid of "page contains secure and non-secure items?"

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm wondering if anybody has written an IIS 7 RE-WRITE rule for getting rid of this error.  Basically, I'm hoping that if the page contains "https://" that all included files on the page would be re-written to "https://".  In theory that should get rid of the error, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting idea. I hadn't though about it using it for that. But it's certainly possible although it adds some overhead to processing the response. Also you won't be able to use GZIP compression (I've included that setting).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="Force HTTPS links when using HTTPS" preCondition="Only for HTML" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^http://(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="https://{R:1}" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="Only for HTML">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

UPDATE:

Support for links to external images in CSS files can be handled in a very similar way with an addition rule. But please note that this is a pretty CPU expensive task as it requires the URL Rewrite module to match the entire CSS file against a regular expression until no match is found anymore.

But for the fun of it, I've added an extra rule that will also replace http links to images in CSS files:

```
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="Force HTTPS links when using HTTPS" preCondition="Only for HTML" stopProcessing="false">
        <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^http://(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="https://{R:1}" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
        </conditions>
    </rule>
    <rule name="Force HTTPS in CSS when using HTTPS" preCondition="Only for CSS">
        <match filterByTags="None" pattern="url\(('|&quot;){0,1}http://(.*?)('|&quot;){0,1}\)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="url({R:1}https://{R:2}{R:3})" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
        </conditions>
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="Only for HTML">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
        </preCondition>
        <preCondition name="Only for CSS">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/css" />
        </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```

Comment: Awesome!  I think that got me about 90% of the way there.  I so still have some .png CSS backgrounds that are coming in through HTTP.  Can I also apply this rule to file extensions?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably much easier to use ["protocol-relative" URLs](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) in your HTML instead.